# How to consume list of azure blob files using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, azure-blob-storage

We have a scenario where we need to consume list of blob files in azure storage container using apache camel. azure-blob in apache camel requires blob name to be passed along with the container name. Is there any way to pass blob name dynamically in from uri?

Comment: Was the answer provided of any help to you ?

Answer (score 0):

Per the official documentation for Apache camel and azure blobs [**here**](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-azure/src/main/docs/azure-blob-component.adoc), A blob name is required:

**URI Format**

```
azure-blob://accountName/containerName[/blobName][?options]
```

*For example in order to download a blob content from the public block blob blockBlob located on the container1 in the camelazure storage account, use the following snippet:*

```
from("azure-blob:/camelazure/container1/blockBlob").
to("file://blobdirectory");
```

An actual work around/Hack that could work for you when downloading multiple blobs, would be to use a list of names for your blobs, use the blob name in the URI as a variable value, which where you can plug in the blob names into, then generate a URl for each blob you have.

I'd recommend also submiting a comment in the Github repo link above for Davclaus@ since he is directly involved in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing it for future references, you can probably pass the regex pattern to get the blobs from Azure like below if the file names are following some naming conventions / extensions.

```
azure-storage-blob://accountName/containerName?accessKey=xxxxx==&operation=listBlobs&regex=BLOB_COR_\d{4}.zip
```

Above URI will fetch files with names BLOB_COR_1111.zip, BLOB_COR_4444.zip and so on. You can update the regex pattern based on your needs.

Reference : https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/azure-storage-blob-component.html#_uri_options (search for regex options)